Can you specify output layer on Align Rasters QGIS?
I am trying to use the Align Rasters tool from QGIS and it is failing to create temporary layers. Is it possible to specify output layers?
I tried this on QGIS version: 3.38.3-Grenoble.
Please see tool GUI here:




I tried to use the raster align tool with QGIS version: 3.39.0-Master and it fails for me too. By the command log it looks like the output file is not defined at all. The tool does not create any name for the temporary layer, and there is no way how user could set the name manually. Feels like a dead-end and a bug in QGIS.

Click the ellipsis button ... to select the input rasters.

Highlight an input raster and click Configure Raster...

There you can configure the output file. Do this for each of the input rasters.


That does work indeed. But it is very odd to configure the output layer with a menu item "Input layers". Especially because user can now select the input layer without going to Configure raster, and then the process will fail. It should be mandatory to configure the output layer, or then the process should create a temporary layer automatically.

@user30184, this has been reported and discussed on QGIS GitHub issues here and here. There are also a couple of stale PRs https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/57127 & https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/57143 based on adding details to the help string and tool tips. I have just submitted a new PR re-implementing the checkParameterValues() method which would block the alg execution and show user a message if output files are not configured for any input rasters.
